# Firebase isn't working on react native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm trying to integrate firebase in react native. But I'm getting small issue with Firebase.
This is my code. I did attach a screen-shot too.
I'm using react native 0.27.

Please help.
Thank you

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput,
  ListView
} from 'react-native';

import Firebase from 'firebase';

class devdacticFirebase extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var itemsRef = new Firebase('https://<myid>.firebaseio.com/items');

    this.state = {
      newTodo: '',
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2})
    };
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <View />
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('devdacticFirebase', () => devdacticFirebase);
```

Comment: i'm using `npm install firebase --save`

Comment: If I remember correctly version 3.x of Firebase doesn't support React native

Comment: yes, if it's correct. it's really bad

Answer (score 1):

The message tells you Firebase is not a constructor, so you can't use `new` on it. The official docs show how to initialize your app:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

var app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
  authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
  databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
  storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But i just do it like tutorial like this way https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html. But let me try your suggest

Comment: Apparently firebase 3 still doesn't work with react-native. I think 2.4.2 used to work, you could use that version for now. Then you have to use it as a constructor like you did in your question

Comment: yes it's correct. i did reinstall version 2.4.2 and it's works. Thanks Pro

Comment: In case anyone wants some more guidance [here is a tutorial](http://bitvbit.blogspot.com/2016/07/firebase-auth-v3-with-react-native.html) for Firebase email/password auth with react native for android that I put together (the same approach can be applied for iOS).

Answer (score 0):

They changed the documentation for initializing firebase projects in JS so it would work in react native.

keep the rest of the code the same replace the constructor with this:

```
var itemsRef = {
apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
};

Firebase.initializeApp(itemsRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```html
expo install firebase
```

instead of yarn  add firebase